# How to Mock a CriteriaQuery.where(EntityRoot.get(ID).in(List<Integer>)

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, criteria, predicatebuilder

I am trying to Mock the function block

```
    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Mock
    private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;

    @Mock
    CriteriaQuery<Entity> criteriaQuery;

    @Mock
    TypedQuery<Entity> typedQuery;

    @Mock
    Predicate predicate;

    @Mock
    Root<Entity> EntityRoot;



 criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(
    EntityRoot.get(ID).in(request.getIdList()),
    criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(EntityRoot.get(columnName),
                                    Request.getTimeRangeFilter().getStartDate())));
```

ID - Static String

i tried mocking with the below code

```
when(criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, predicate))).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
```

but for the line `EntityRoot.get(ID).in(request.getIdList())`

i get the below error

[image]

What am i doing wrong here

Comment: Please add the production code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mock
Path<Object> path; 

when(EntityRoot.get(anyString())).thenReturn(path);
        when(path.in(Mockito.anyList())).thenReturn(predicate);
```

This solution worked finally.